# How to write Jquery .keyup function on elements that are loaded by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page that loads elements to itself via ajax after the user interacts with it.

My trouble is I can't get Jquery to recognize the elements that have been later to work fromt he function refresh_current_items.

My Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function() {        
        refresh_open_handling_units();
        refresh_closed_handling_units();    
        refresh_avaiable_shippable_items();                         

    });

    $('#length_imp').on({
            keyup: function() { var val1 = 2.54 * $("#length_imp").val();
                                $("#length_cm").val(val1); }                            
        });

    function refresh_current_items(unit){
        $.post("ajax_print_current_unit.php", { unit: unit,
                                                            save_flag: 'save_button'}, function(b)
                    {
                        $('#added_items').html(b).show();
                    });
    }
    ......
```

HTML that is loaded via ajax:

```
inches <input type="text" id="length_imp">
cm <input type="text" id="length_cm">
```

The only console error I get is "Failed to Load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

I know this isn't the most optimal way to do it, but I ended up with code that looks like this:

```
$(document).on( 'keyup', '#length_imp', function () {
        var val1 = 2.54 * $("#length_imp").val();
        $("#length_cm").val(val1);
    }
);
$(document).on( 'keyup', '#length_cm', function () {
            var val1 = 0.3937 * $("#length_cm").val();
        $("#length_imp").val(val1);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `$('#length_imp').on` attaches no handler since there is no #length_imp when you run it.
You can attach the listener to the `document` and check if the target is `#length_imp`

```
$(document).on( 'keyup', '#length_imp', function () {
        var val1 = 2.54 * $("#length_imp").val();
        $("#length_cm").val(val1);
    }
);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/s7bxmhfL/)

Comment: As a side note: Do not use `document` as your **parent** context. Use something above (but much closer) to where your generated code will be.  Let's say a `<div>` that's wrapped around them all. Otherwise this keyup event gets bubbled on EVERY keyup on your page.